# iimPlay doesn't seems to work even in both javascript and scripting interface

Tags: javascript, macros, automation, imacros

My name.csv file populated with data of username (col1), and active/inactive status (col2).
I want script that will check wether the username in current loop is active or not. If it is active, it will play activeUname.iim . Otherwise, it'll play inactiveUname.iim .

I have tried this code.

```
iimPlayCode("TAB T=1" + "\n" + "SET !DATASOURCE name.csv" + "\n" + "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2" + "\n" + "SET !LOOP 2" + "\n" + "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}");

var a = {{!COL5}};
if(a=="Active"){
    iimSet("data", a);
    iimplay("activeUname.iim");
} else{
    iimSet("data",a);
    iimplay("inactiveUname.iim");
}
```

Also the scripting interface

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 40
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !DATASOURCE name.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 9
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a = \"{{!COL5}}\";if(a=="Active"){iimSet("data", a);iimplay("activeUname.iim");} else{iimSet("data",a);iimplay("inactiveUname.iim");}")
```

But not working either.

Have tried also some other combination value like

```
if(a==Active)
```

or

```
var a={{!COL1}}
```

or

```
var a=\"{{!COL1}}"
```

and some other minor thing in case I left something off but still couldn't get it.

What my activeUname.iim / inactiveUname looks like accessing the data passed with iimSet

```
URL GOTO=https://website.com/{{data}}
```

The error message, something like

```
wrong format of SET command
```

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong:

```
var a = {{!COL2}};
```

It's right:

```
iimPlayCode("SET !DATASOURCE name.csv" + "\n" + "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL2}}");
var a = iimGetExtract();
```

It's too wrong once again:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var a = \"{{!COL5}}\";if(a=="Active"){iimSet("data", a);iimplay("activeUname.iim");} else{iimSet("data",a);iimplay("inactiveUname.iim");}")
```

You must read [this](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface)!

Comment: Oh. So this line should work, right?

`SET !VAR1 EVAL("iimPlayCode("SET !EXTRACT {{!COL5}}");var a = iimGetExtract();if(a=="Bukalapak"){iimSet("data", a);iimplay("IzinBukalapak.iim");} else{iimSet("data",a);iimplay("IzinToped.iim");}")`

Comment: That's too wrong over again. You really have to read about the [`EVAL` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL) .